# Finding the sum of the digits in the exponents when multiplied out

Tags: exponential-function

When multiplied out, what is the sum of the digits in the number $7^2  2^{2017}  5^{2018}$. I’m guessing there’s some trick to solve this problem, but I don’t know what it is. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial

Comment: As for the sum of digits: My hint would be "compute modulo 10".

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

It's $49\times5\times10^{2017}$

Comment: Thanks for the help!